# Are there any ways to align a textbox vertically middle within a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a panel, i want to align it vertically middle within a panel, the pic shows what i want

[image]

Any one know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) control.

1. Drag a `TableLayoutPanel` onto your form
2. Set the `Dock` property to `Fill`
3. Remove one of the columns from the `Columns` collection because by default you will get 2 columns.
4. Add one more `Row` to your panel because by default you will get 2.

Then:

1. Put the textbox into the second row.
2. Set the `Dock` property to `Fill`

[image]

Set the sizes for the rows for the `TableLayoutPanel` as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sorry i didnt mean you but by you i was referring the downvoter because I have no idea why they decided to downvote. Maybe there is a valid reason but we will never know. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

Align a control in parent vertically:

```
InsidePanel.Location = new Point(
    0, (OutsidePanel.Height - InsidePanel.Height) / 2
);
```

Align a control in parent horizontally:

```
InsidePanel.Location = new Point(
    (OutsidePanel.Width - InsidePanel.Width) / 2, 0
);
```

If you do have form resizing, you will need to make sure this is added to you resize event handler to make sure the controls stay centered.